# ESRI ArcGIS for Server AMI for Amazon EC2 reserved instances

Tags: arcgis-server, amazon-ec2, cloud-gis, amazon-web-services

I read several online documents on using ESRI's Cloud Builder to optmimally set and fire up ArcServer AMIs on Amazon EC2. However, everything seems oriented toward selecting and launching ***on-demand*** EC2 instances, not ***reserved*** instances.

Does anyone know how to get started with ArcServer AMIs on reserved EC2 instances? Does Cloud Builder not allow this type of set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reserved Instance cost savings automatically get applied to an on-demand instance that matches the:

- instance type
- Availability Zone
- platform
- tenancy

..of the Reserved Instance that you have purchased. So, assuming you have access to your AWS Console, you can go in there, search for and purchase a Reserved Instance that matches the above specs of your on-demand EC2 ArcGIS Server instance, and that Reserved Instance will get applied to the matching on-demand instance. Now, that said, I have never used CloudBuilder, but I am assuming all it does is design and possibly deploy an AMI for you, which should then be available to you in your list of EC2 instances in the AWS Console. The [docs on Reserved Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/reserved-instances/getting-started/) are pretty thorough, I suggest you read through them at length before making your purchase.

Comment: So you are saying I should first fire up the on-demand EC2 (via AWS or CloudBuilder) AMIs and, secondly, use the AWS console to purchase reserved instances that match the ones I started above? Does this mean I would terminate the on-demand instances once I purchase the reserved ones or the association is automatically done by AWS? I am assuming part of this will be in the doc you recommended, but just making sure I understand the steps you are suggesting..

Comment: You do not terminate the on-demand instance. So as long as the specs of the on-demand instance match those of the reserved instance, yes, the association is done automatically by AWS.